# Div not showing in a jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page using bootstrap 3 framework that has a button which when pressed collects data from another page (mydata.php) with ajax and echoes it out within `<div id="results">` on the page. The code works fine but as soon as I add `<div class=\"col-xs-6\">` to `mydata.php` nothing appears on the page although I can see it within firebug.

If I change  `$("#results").append(html);` to  `$("#results").text(html);` the html echoes onto the page but as text without any formatting. If I remove  `<div class=\"col-xs-6\">` from mypage.php the data gets displayed on the page as expected. Why is the data from mydata.php not displayed when I add `<div class=\"col-xs-6\">`?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-centered">

 <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="search" id="myButton" class="search_button btn btn-small btn-default btn-pull-right">Press</button>
</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div id="results"><!--data displayed here-->
</div>

</div><!--Row-->
</div><!--Cont-->
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
      var btn    = $("#myButton").val();
         var data            = 'btn='+ btn;
         // if location is not empty
        if(data) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mydata.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(html){

                    $("#results").append(html);
              }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

mydata.php looks like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {

echo "

 <div class=\"col-xs-6\">

<ul>
<li><h4>Data in this Div</h4></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class=\"col-xs-6\">

<ul>
<li><h4>And Data in this Div</h4></li>
</ul>
</div>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using '\' back slash in ` <div class=\"col-xs-6\">` ?

Comment: Instead of `$("#results").append(html);`, you should use `$("#results").html(html);`

Comment: @SilentCoder it's because the string itself is delimited with `"`, so the internal ones need escaping.

Comment: But thats in the PHP part... It is not the actual html.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the explanation. Got the idea. :D

Comment: i did not find any problem .

Comment: change  $("#results").append(html); to  $("#results").html($("#results").html()+html);

Comment: For those suggesting to use .html() over .append(), do know that in this case they do the same, but .html() would overwrite content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem actually lies with css and not jquery.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not add jQuery library then include it

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-centered">

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <button type="submit" name="btn" value="search" id="myButton"
                        class="search_button btn btn-small btn-default btn-pull-right">Press
                </button>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div id="results"><!--data displayed here-->
        </div>

    </div><!--Row-->
</div><!--Cont-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $("#myButton").click(function () {
                var btn = $("#myButton").val();
                var data = 'btn=' + btn;
                // if location is not empty
                if (data) {
                    // ajax call
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/edit.php", // your file path
                        data: data,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#results").append(html); // if you want to replace results div then change $("#results").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

it is working fine my side, i have tested in my local side

this is output: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ajax part works without problems... Are you sure you are receiving that exact HTML?

```js
$('#result').append("<div class=\"col-xs-6\">"+
"<ul>"+
"<li><h4>Data in this Div</h4></li>"+
"</ul>"+
"</div>"+
""+
"<div class=\"col-xs-6\">"+
""+
"<ul>"+
"<li><h4>And Data in this Div</h4></li>"+
"</ul>"+
"</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've discovered the code does work but the problem lies with the css in my  page. When I remove it all the code appears so for some reason the css framework I have is hiding it. Thanks again.

Comment: Alright, please close the question then, as it is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
  var form = jQuery("#form");
  $.ajax({
        url: 'mydata.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  form.serialize(),       
        cache: false,       
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data==true){               
                $("#results").append(data);
            }
    if(data==false){

            }
        },
        error: function(){
        }           
   });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: if(data==true) and if(data==false)? I mean, really?